# Value of type 'UIImageView' has no member 'kf' in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, swift4, kingfisher

I am using Kingfisher library for downloading an image from URL and setting to UIIMageView in Swift 4 project.

I know there are API changes between Kingfisher 2 and Kingfisher 3

https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/wiki/Kingfisher-3.0-Migration-Guide

My project was working a few weeks back but after upgrading Xcode, cannot compile the project. It gives error

[image]

I have tried deleting derived data and all possible solutions from the links I have got it from google.

Anyone facing the same issue with Kingfisher library?

**Note: I have manually added Kingfisher library in the project. Not by pod or other package managers.**

Comment: your kingfisher integration is through Cocoapods?

Comment: No, I have added manually

Comment: Did you try with the clean and rebuild combo?

Comment: Yes, I tried this option

Comment: @nikhilgohil11 as you said there are API changes between KF2 and KF3. Adding manually is not the best solution, you should maybe use Cocoapods which can be easier to manage versions. Maybe try to remove Kingfisher from your project and install it again...

Comment: Thanks! But adding manually was working before and now it's not working. For now, I have used the pod.

Comment: I am facing same issue with Swift4.2 but only while iPhone5C attached during running app, on other device no compiler errors. Any idea ?

Comment: @technerd how did you add KF to the project? Manually or through cocoapods?

Comment: Using Cocoapods

Comment: Can you remove all pod and install again? Like removing all pod 'pod_name' from pod file and do 'pod install', clean the project and install all pods again. For me, it worked when I reinstall all pods and clean the project.

Answer (score 3):

Use this pod:

```
pod 'Kingfisher'
```

Update Your Pod:

```
pod update
```

Import this library in your class file:

```
import Kingfisher
```

Comment: Thanks! I am aware of this. Let me know if you find the same issue while manually adding a framework.

Answer (score 1):

This simple line work for me , although we normally don't need to import it

```
import Kingfisher
```

Answer (score 0):

**Build Settings>> Search Paths >>Framework Search Path>>Change path to ./ (selecting recursive.)**

[image]